# Use methods of the same name in one class Java Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-videoview

I have an app that shows video streaming using video views.

Since the video formats I want to show are not supported by Android Versions <2.0 I am using the vitamio library to show the videos on older devices.

However Vitamio is way slower than Android video view libraries and i don't want to use it on all devices; i just want to use it on older ones.

However the names of the libraries and the methods are the same:
i.e.

```
import android.media.MediaController;
import io.vov.vitamio.MediaController;
```

In the class I only import the android Media controller and i access the vitamio one like this:

```
 io.vov.vitamio.widget.MediaController mediacontroller = new io.vov.vitamio.widget.MediaController(parentActivity);
```

which works fine until I want to access one of the methods of the vitamio library. For example:

```
videoView.io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(video);
```

This does not work as the correct use is:

```
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
```

If I do that then the Android media player is accessed and the code isn't correct.
How can I access a method with the same name in the same class. I want to be able to use both methods based on the device of the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't have to put the full path for both classes. import just 1 class and the other use it by path.

Comment: I am not importing both of the classes and i am accessing one of them by path. I am having problems accessing the methods as they have the same name of the imported class.

Comment: in that case you should show us all the calls you are making of those classes so we could give you a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
videoView.io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(video);
```

By doing that you are trying to call the method in a static way.

You should be declaring your videoView variable as an instance of `videoView.io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView` and then call the appropriate method :

```
// declaration of variable as an instance of the correct class
videoView.io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView videoView;
// now, use the method
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
```

Comment: The problem is that the vitamio library uses Android VideoView. I need to declare the video view variale like this:  private VideoView videoView;

Comment: Is videoView.io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView a subclass of the original Android version ?

Comment: Then I really don't understand why declaring the variable with the full package name to avoid compiler confusion is not working for you... Why exactly do you need to declare your variable as private VideoView videoView; ?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right, it should be working by declaring the variable with full package name. I guess i am having errors  somewhere else in my code.

Comment: If you have errors, don't hesitate asking another question ;) Don't forget to share the full LogCat error and relevant code, it will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your class VideoView is from type "videoView.io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView" and not "android.widget.VideoView".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `videoView.io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(video)`, it should be `videoView.setVideoURI(video)` where videoView is of type `io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView`.

If it's an `Object`, you can cast explicitly: `((io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView)myObject).setVideoURI(video)`.